# Multiply Function with two parameters

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to learn C++ and I got stuck at Functions. I understand the concept but I can't figure out how I can multiply the two parameters I submited to it.

So, I want to have a function called multiply.

```
void multiply(int first, int second)
{

}
```

And I want to call it in _tmain with

```
cout << multiply(2,3) <<endl;
```

And when it prints out, I want to see the value of (2*3). 
Any ideas? :(

Comment: `int multiply(int first, int second) {return first*second;}` There are many only resource to learn that.

Comment: You need to learn what a function is. How to understand declaration. You do not really understand the concept IMO. Yours say that the function does not return anything, and you are trying to put this anything into `cout`. This is one the most basic concepts of programming. I am also afraid, the question will get downvoted, because of failing the meeting of basic understanding the concepts, although it is very properly formatted, and probably is better than many other questions for homeworks and asking for code. It is just too basic stuff.

Comment: "void" designates a function that doesn't return anything.  "int" as per the answers designates a function that returns an integer.

Comment: You're going to struggle with C++ is you're having problems like this. Get yourself a good book and spend some time with it.

Comment: Take care naming your function `multiply()`! note there is already a `std::multiply()` function defined, where declarations could clash with yours.

Comment: Go back and read the introduction to functions again. Pay particular attention to the concept of a "return value".

Comment: @RobKennedy This is not too broad, it is very specific. It is a very good question in terms of quality. It is just too basic. Also how can you say question is too broad, when people give correct answers in 4-5 lines lol.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It would only clash if you wrote `using namespace std;` or `using std::multiply;`. No-one would do that, would they?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Said nothing more than _Take care_ ;) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int multiply(int first, int second)
{
    return first * second;
}
```

is what you want.

Notice that the function's return type (the type before the function's name in its declaration) is now an `int`, meaning that when you call that function, you get an int back. Then, you define the value of the `int` being returned with the `return` keyword.

Comment: Or `double`, but unlikely at this stage.

Comment: if the explicit parameters are 2 integer values, the result will be an integer.  Period.

Answer (score 1):

```
int multiply(int first, int second)
{
return first*second;
}
```

Comment: I prefer @Martin_J 's answer because delimiting the operator by a space is more standard coding practice.

Comment: Hi @La-comadreja! he was also 7 seconds faster to publish the solution, so he deserves the points ;)